# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to update my DB rows by using primary key.But facing this Exception

### Exception

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="edit/product/success" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editProduct(@ModelAttribute ("prdt") Product p)
{   
ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("pl");
model.addObject("Update","Updated Successfully");
pd.update(p);
return model;       
}
```

### Dao Impl

```
public void update( Product p) {
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
session.update(p);
session.flush();
session.close();
}
```

### Jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#mfg" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<br>

<h2 align="center">PRODUCT FORM</h2><hr>
<div class="col-md-2 "></div>
<div align="center"><div class="container"><div class="col-md-8 ">


<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit/product/success" commandName="prdt" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<table class="table table-hover">

<tr>
<td> <form:label  path="product_Name"> Enter Product Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input type="text" path="product_Name" class="form-control" value="${d.product_Name }"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <form:label path="descripction"> Enter Product Descripction</form:label></td>
<td><form:input type="text" path="descripction"  class="form-control" value="${d.descripction }"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <form:label  path="price"> Enter Product Price</form:label></td>
<td><form:input type="text" path="price"  class="form-control" value="${d.price }" />
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td> <form:label  path="mfg_Date"> Enter Manufacture Date</form:label></td>
<td><form:input type="text" id="mfg" path="mfg_Date" class="form-control" value ="${d.mfg_Date}"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td> <label> Choose Image</label></td>
<td><form:input type="file" path="image" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Save Changes" class="form-control"/>

</form:form>

</div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

please check and let me know my Mistake..i have looked in it.but not found any irregularity.

### Note:

Data retrieve works fine.facing trouble in Update only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this approach :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.update(p);
session.flush();
session.close();
tx.commit();
```

This error usually caused when the hibernate can't find all the rows it needs to update. Meaning that when you try to update some objects that were pulled from the DB they don't really exist anymore (or never existed in the first place).

It might be because another thread is deleting them or that the DB's isolation mode is set to read_uncommited and so rows that were created by another transaction failed to save (due to a transaction failure) and don't exist anymore.

Comment: but i have defined Transaction in hibernate config.

Comment: Still facing the same

Comment: Can you share all your files !

Comment: For update() and saveOrUpdate() methods, id generator value should be there in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187799/404-error-in-associate-mapping   help me

Answer (score 0):

Check the product entity which u are trying to save to the database. Hibernate tries to look up for an entity with the ID(Primary key value), and if the pk value is changed in the entity and the update is called on this entity then the above error occurs.

Check the entity is having the same id, or the id getting replaced or setting to null somewhere. The id may be null in your case.