# 404 Error in Associate Mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

---

I am developing shopping cart web app which have completed up to display product to add cart. I am trying to map every customer (One To One) to cart Entity, cart entity (one to one) to cart item Entity, and cart item entity (Many to One) to Product entity. But I got a 404 error.
Please check my code below.

### Mapping plan:

Customer-----one to one------>Cart----one to one---->Cart Item----Many to one--->Product

### Customer Entity

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Cid") 
private int customerId;
@Column(name="password")
@NotEmpty(message="Name is mandatory")
private String password;
@Column(name="Email") 
@NotEmpty(message="Name is mandatory")
private String email;
@NotEmpty(message="First Name is mandatory")
@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstName;
@NotEmpty(message="Last Name is mandatory")
@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastName;
@Column(name="Mobile")
@NotEmpty(message="Mobile is mandatory")
private String mobile;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="address_id")
private Address delAdderss;
private boolean enabled;
private String role;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="cart_id")
private Cart cart;

public Cart getCart() {
    return cart;
}
public void setCart(Cart cart) {
    this.cart = cart;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}
public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(int name) {
    this.customerId = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public Address getDelAdderss() {
    return delAdderss;
}
public void setDelAdderss(Address delAdderss) {
    this.delAdderss = delAdderss;
}

}
```

### Cart Entity

```
package com.model;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Cart {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int cart_id;
@Column
private double total;
@Column
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="item_id")
private CartItem cartItem;
public int getCart_id() {
return cart_id;
}
public void setCart_id(int cart_id) {
this.cart_id = cart_id;
}
public double getTotal() {
return total;
}
public void setTotal(double total) {
this.total = total;
}
public CartItem getCartItem() {
return cartItem;
}
public void setCartItem(CartItem cartItem) {
this.cartItem = cartItem;
}


}
```

### Cart Item Entity

```
package com.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class CartItem {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int item_id;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private List<Product> product;
public int getItem_id() {
return item_id;
}
public void setItem_id(int item_id) {
this.item_id = item_id;
}
public List<Product> getProduct() {
return product;
}
public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
this.product = product;
}

}
```

### Product Entity

```
package com.model;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
public class Product {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column
private String product_Name;
@Column
private String descripction;
@Column
private int price;
@Column
private Date mfg_Date;
@Transient
private MultipartFile image;

public MultipartFile getImage() {
return image;
}
public void setImage(MultipartFile image) {
this.image = image;
}
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getProduct_Name() {
return product_Name;
}
public void setProduct_Name(String product_Name) {
this.product_Name = product_Name;
}
public String getDescripction() {
return descripction;
}
public void setDescripction(String descripction) {
this.descripction = descripction;
}
public int getPrice() {
return price;
}
public void setPrice(int price) {
this.price = price;
}
public Date getMfg_Date() {
return mfg_Date;
}
public void setMfg_Date(Date mfg_Date) {
this.mfg_Date = mfg_Date;
}
}
```

Comment: Exception:Error creating bean with name 'productController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using cart item entity, According to me it should be Customer one on one with Cart, And a Cart as one to many with Products. I think there is no need for cart items table/entity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352216/http-status-400-bad-request-jslt-error?noredirect=1#comment73768163_43352216