# 400 Bad request while uploading multiple files in Spring MVC using modelAttribute for form submission

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm a novice user in Spring MVC. I tried designing a form uploading multiple files and redirected the action of the form submission to the controller url and like wise defined the command name of the form as the model attribute needed to be bind with. So i'm assuming the form parameters will be mapped as defined 'path' in the tags with the model attribute's parameters.

I'm posting my code below:

SampleForm.jsp

```
  <form:form id="exampleFullForm" commandName="attribute1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate" class="fv-form fv-form-bootstrap" action="url1">

      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" name="accnumber" path="account_number"/>
    <form:input type="file" name="proof1" required="" file-model="proof1" path="files[0].file" id="files[0].file" class="filestyle"  />
<form:input type="file" required="" name="proof2" file-model="proof2" path="files[1].file" id="files[1].file" class="filestyle" style="position:inherit;"/>
     </form:form>
```

MyController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "url1", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="multipart/form-data")
    public ModelAndView createNewMerchantAccount(@ModelAttribute("attribute1") ModelName modelParam, Map<String, Object> models) throws IOException{
        //Do Something
        return new ModelAndView("successpage");

    }
```

Model.java

```
 public Model() {
               files.add(new FileBucket());
                files.add(new FileBucket());
        }

    @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
    @Column(name= "account_number")
        private Integer account_number;
    @Transient
        private List<FileBucket> files = new ArrayList<FileBucket>();

        //Getters and setters
        public List<FileBucket> getFiles() {
            return files;
        }
        public void setFiles(List<FileBucket> files) {
            this.files = files;
        }
```

After form submission, i get an error 400 bad Request. I'm attaching the snapshot of my post parameters as well. Files are getting attached properly as per my knowledge.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary4AkLoHMTlZVo90nY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0].file"; filename="Refund.png"
Content-Type: image/png
PNG

���
IHDR��4��2���Ä_����sRGB�®Îé���gAMA��±üa���  pHYs��Ä��Ä+��yÖIDATx^íÝ}+ë}Ø÷ßí?
`Ô2 Y#ßÆæú`Û+VÉ¬
4Æ¶$9ô 8
7îµY£

------WebKitFormBoundary4AkLoHMTlZVo90nY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[1].file"; filename="Order_Refund.png"
Content-Type: image/png


 èRÂê^Ýj»iQä@"ûWY¶±.sâTê^ì q�¹ËT¥n½=&ë»,rÚ@p¯dYìó<óÌðg^ÈåîYóý\Ì=$gæg^óÌÏËÎB�[ãõ7Þ7O
>mßU}ñòðáCû�����`{}þóÉ¾������;&������­A@������ÀÖ    ������`k0(°e��ÜÏ}îsöÕí{íµ×ì+��bzP
 À!     ��nh¾öß~`ñsÿ½Ú.M��P£������Ø*4������l
�������¶M����K;Ïa��XM����7kÞýÙÙïËÜ~��°.����ßÿÙÑHwÚÿ¬Ìõ¼µ¦¨IÓÿúæ��ÔG@���_ø?ËbñG2

24
------WebKitFormBoundary4AkLoHMTlZVo90nY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="account_number"
```

FileBucket Model:

```
public class FileBucket {

    MultipartFile file;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

And my headers:
[Headers_attached_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D4zH.png)

Help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: What is that `FileBucket` thing? Imho that should be a `MultipartFile` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please find the class FileBucket added in the question now.

Comment: Your question isn't complete, you are only showing partial stuff, the classes don\t match. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352216/http-status-400-bad-request/43359895#43359895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling for hours, I figured out a way to rescue.

In my controller, I had forgot to add binding result and that's how i debugged the error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "url1", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="multipart/form-data")
    public ModelAndView createNewMerchantAccount(@ModelAttribute("attribute1") ModelName modelParam,BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> models) throws IOException{

        //Do Something
 if(result.hasErrors()) {
               System.out.println("Result Error Occured"+result.getAllErrors());
            }
        return new ModelAndView("successpage");

    }
```

And the error appeared to be in casting exception of one of the model's attribute.

And after casting the parameter to be of defined type, it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code sample which can help you.

In your model, add the below instant variable:-

```
class Product{
//other variables
      @Transient
        private MultipartFile[] productImage;
//getter setter
}
```

In your jsp, add the below codes sample:-

```
<label class="control-label" for="productImage">Upload Picture</label>
            <form:errors path="productImage" cssStyle="color:#ff0000;" />
            <table id="fileTable" style="border-spacing: 5;">
            <tr>
            <td><form:input path="productImage" type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-buttonBefore="true" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><form:input path="productImage" type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-buttonBefore="true" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

In controller use the sample below code snippet :-

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/product/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
          public String addProductPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
        MultipartFile[] productImage = product.getProductImage();//you can get file here

        //...
return "successpage";
        }
```

I hope this will help to get solution.

Comment: Thank you @soewin for the answer but it seems to give the same 400 error.

Comment: @AnkitaGoyal, The 400 Bad Request error is often caused by entering or pasting the wrong URL in the address window but there are some other relatively common causes as well. Can you check your post URL correct or not. If u r hitting correct URL then after the controller process, ur returning wrong URL path or the page ur returning is not same as the path of your URL. Better is you should debug.

Comment: I figured the problem to be with '@ModelAttribute' annotation. Thank you for the help.