# Why does BindingResult need to be put as a method parameter while uploading via JSP a MultipartFile image as byte[] to DB?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jpa

I am having similar problem to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352216/http-status-400-bad-request) and thanks to the tips there I managed to get my stuff 'working', however, I am curious why is the `BindingResult` needed? I noticed that when I add it as a method parameter, the addition of the image is fine, even though I am not using bindingResult in the body of the method at all.

And yet, when I remove the `BindingResult` from the arguments, I get the 400:

> "The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)."

What is even more interesting, the method seems not be even called, because when I place a breakpoint there, debugger does not stop there.

I read about the `BindingResult` a bit (maybe too little), but all the posts here stated that this is used for the validation purposes.

At first I thought this might be connected with the `MulitpartFile` as an `@RequestParam`, but this is not the case I suppose, at least not fully. Although, when I change the enctype from `addProduct.jsp` the method is being called without breaking, but then, the upload obviously does not work.

To summarize, I got it working, but I would like to understand it a bit more or get some tips, maybe I shouldn't be using `byte[]` or upload the image differently. Here is a little code.

HomeController.java

```
@PostMapping("/admin/productInventory/addProduct")
public String addProductPost(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult bindingResult,
                             @RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile multipartImageFile) {

    try {
        if (multipartImageFile != null && !multipartImageFile.isEmpty())
            product.setImageFile(multipartImageFile.getBytes());
        productDAO.addProduct(product);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    ...

    @Lob
    private byte[] imageFile;

    @Transient
    private String base64EncodedImage;

    (Getters & Setters)
}
```

addProduct.jsp

```
    <form:form id="imageForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/productInventory/addProduct"
               method="post" commandName="product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productImage" class="control-label">Upload Image</label>
        <form:input path="imageFile" id="productImage" type="file" class="form:input-large"/>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
    <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory"/>" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a>
    </form:form>
```

**EDIT**

From what I suspect is that the BindingResult catches the IllegalArgumentException that is being thrown when the application tries to attach MultipartFile to model, which has an array of bytes, not the MultipartFile. On the other hand, the MultipartFile cannot be persisted, that is why I decided to use byte[]. But if I wanted to use the bindingResult for validation I would still have error in bindingResult.

This is the error BindingResult shows:

> "Field error in object 'product' on field 'imageFile': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@5d4938c0]; codes [typeMismatch.product.imageFile,typeMismatch.imageFile,typeMismatch.[B,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [product.imageFile,imageFile]; arguments []; default message [imageFile]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'imageFile'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property 'imageFile[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile']"

Comment: It needs the `BindingResult` because that way you can handle the exception. If you don't it will fail with a bad request (as due to the missing `BindingResult` you cannot handle it yourself). The problem is that you want a `byte[]` in your object but you are actually passing a `MultipartFile`. To not get an error rename your form field to something else then `imageFile`, that way it won't be bound to the model object and as such won't fail. Or disable the field from binding using an `@InitBinder` method and use `dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("imageFile")` to prevent binding.

Comment: If I rename the form field to st else I am unable to get to that page due to the fact that there is no such field in the model. When I add the field to the model `@Transient MultipartFile multipartImageFile` and apply it in the form, submitting the form I get another 400: `Required request part 'imageFile' is not present.`
As for the `@InitBinder` it is working well, but it still seems to me like a workaround.
However, I am wondering whether I took good approach to the problem. I am hesitant towards using `product.setImageFile(multipartImageFile.getBytes());` in my `HomeContoller.`

Comment: Don't use `form:input` in the case of a renamed argument. You should. only use the spring form tags for fields you want to. bind to the model NOT for things you don't want to bind to the model. The main problem is you are using your entity directly as a form object. You cannot submit/bind a `byte[]` directly, you will have to do manual work for that.

Comment: So, ultimately the `.getBytes()` and manual setter is inevitable? In that case, maybe a better approach would be to make a `DspObject`, a `BusinessObject` and a `ConverterObject` between the two. What do you think?

But then comes the problem of converting from `byte[]` to `MultipartFile`...

Comment: Why would you need to convert it back? It doesn't do anything. You don't need the additional object you just shouldn't use `form:input` for the `imageFile` just a regular `input` and use a different 'name` so that you can use `@RequestParam` to obtain it. As I stated the `form:input` should only be used for fields you want to bind to your form object.

Comment: I think I will just stick to @InitBinder, because when I use regular `input` and change the `name` I get the same error about `imageFile not being present`. However, this might be due to that I use it within `form:form` as I want other fields to be bound to the model.

Comment: No it is because you still have that as a `@RequestParam` you should rename that as well.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. Now both ways it works. Now I wonder about the best way to view the image, but this is another discussion. Thanks for the help!